# JUnit4 Empty Parameterized Test

Tags: java, junit, junit4, parameterized

I've build a xquery Testframework, sometimes I want to test header and inbound and sometimes just Header for example.

I've got therefore 4 Testcases:

```
headerAndBody, 
headerAndBodyTestsuite,
Header,
HeaderTestsuite
```

I search the directory for data and construct the tester from it.

And here is the Error:

```
@Test
    public void someTest() throws Exception{
            if (listHdrInbPayTestSuites.size() > 0) {
                assertTrue(buildTest.testHdrInbPay(testSuiteIdentifier));

            }
        }
```

The list is **EMPTY!** but JUnit still says the test ran twice. How can I fix it to say it's an empty test?

Edit:

```
@Parameter
public String testSuiteIdentifier; (which actually has 2 items)
```

Edit:(One Testsuite can contain several testcases, so I can't just take another parameter, because I want to identify them by Testsuite name.)
[image: One Testsuite can contain several testcases, so I can't just take another parameter, because I want to identify them by Testsuite name.]

**Temporary solution:**
Found a workaround to ignore these tests:

```
@Before
    public void shouldRunTest() {
        Assume.assumeTrue(listHeaderAndBodyTestSuites.size() > 0);
    }
```

I'm not really satisfied with this solution since the information "test skipped" can be misleading.

Any other approaches/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit does not support the concept of an empty test. An ignored test is the concept that comes closest to it.

In order to not increase the test count you have to ensure that the data values are not part of the parameters. This means you have to remove them within your `@Parameters` method. Here is an example that removes some data values for the Fibonacci test example of the `Parameterized` runner's documentation.

```
@Parameters
public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
    Collection<Object[]> currentData = Arrays.asList(
        new Object[][] {
            { 0, 0 },
            { 1, 1 },
            { 2, 1 },
            { 3, 2 },
            { 4, 3 },
            { 5, 5 },
            { 6, 8 }
        }
    );
    return currentData.stream()
        .filter( dataSet -> dataSet[1] > 3 )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() );
 }
```